# Why we don't have a Triage and/or Help and Improvement Review Queues?

Tags: support, review-page

I see that in the StackOverflow Reviews Queues we can access to the *Triage* and *Help and Improvement* Review Queues. However we don't have here those two kind of review. Why?

Comment: Would you spend a lot of time in them if we did? :) Because of the low volume of questions here it's pretty easy to spot questions from new/inexperienced users. I guess the idea is that's enough for the lower traffic sites, whereas SO has such volume that actually grouping them together somewhere becomes really useful

Comment: @clive I can spend my time helping with this. I make this kind of review in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Clive said, we don't have it because we have a lower traffic, compared to Stack Overflow.
Also, Stack Overflow is the *test* site for many features; once the feature doesn't need *calibration* anymore, Stack Exchange could decide to implement it in other sites too.

Comment: So, we need to wait until the feature are ready to all the network?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It happened with the new profile and other features.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer ready for, and **needed in** all the network. Review audits are ready for years, and yet they are not enabled here. Who knows about these queues? They may share the same fate.